# Python Regex : Match a particular string and space or coma before

Tags: python, regex, option-type

I am pretty new to regex and a little confused with my example :

I have titles like theses :

- Superman
- Superman HD
- Superman (HD)
- Superman,HD
- Superman,(HD)
- Hands on
- Hands, on

What I want to do is match whatever HD or (HD) that will be at the end of the title and also the "," or " " that is just before.

Typically here with my example, I want to match everything but the "Superman" and match nothing in the last 2 titles.

I am trying something like that :

```
[\s,HD|\(HD\))]
```

But it's also matching all the other "H" "D" "," and " ".

Can anyone give a small help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
/(?:,| )(?:HD|\(HD\))/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nP7sS7/5)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the end-of-line marker `$` in your regex, and to make the other characters optional:

```
/\s*,?\(?HD\)?$/
```

Comment: The text in that regex checker is wrong, there should be just one line

Answer (score 0):

For your example, please try this pattern:

```
/(?<=\bSuperman)(\s*,?(?:HD|\(HD\)))/g
```

EXPLANATION:

```
(?<=\bSuperman)  # positive lookbehind to assert 'Superman' is behind
\s*              # match 0 or more spaces
,?               # match literal , 0 or one time
(?:HD|\(HD\))    # the ending could be 'HD' or '(HD)'
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eG3hZ5/5).

Answer (score -1):

If it's everything after the superman then use this positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=Superman).*
```

If it's just HD or (HD) with or without , then:

```
(?<=Superman)\s?,?HD|\(HD\)
```